# Why do resolutions become smaller after a image file be read by program?

Tags: android, image, screen, drawable, resolution

I meet a problem:

I have images file having different sizes. (hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi)

When I used the image files in the in the hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi devices, it's good.

But when the device is xxxhdpi, the resolutions of the image files was became smaller.

I don't know why it had happened.

For example:

I have 2 devices, one's resolution is xxhdpi, another one is xxxhdpi.

And I have 2 image files, one is put in the folder "drawable-xxhdpi", it's resolution is 1080x1920. Another one is put in the folder "drawable-xxxhdpi", it's resolution is 1440x2560.

When I read the image files, problem was appeared.

The case xxhdpi: 
The original picture is 1080x1920, and image that was read is 1080x1920 still.

**The case xxxhdpi:**
**The original picture is 1440x2560, but the image that was read became 1260x2240.**

This is my code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            Log.i("SettingCardFragment", String.format("%37s%dx%d",
                    "Screen resolution: ", metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels));

            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.background);
            Log.i("SettingCardFragment", String.format("%37s%dx%d",
                    "(Drawable)Background.png resolution: ", drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()));

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background);
            Log.i("SettingCardFragment", String.format("%37s%dx%d",
                    "(Bitmap)Background.png resolution: ", bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()));
```

I use the code to check the resolution of the picture that was read.

And I got the result in xxhdpi device:

```
SettingCardFragment:                   Screen resolution: 1080x1776
SettingCardFragment: (Drawable)Background.png resolution: 1080x1920
SettingCardFragment:   (Bitmap)Background.png resolution: 1080x1920
```

**And the result in xxxhdpi device:**

```
SettingCardFragment:                   Screen resolution: 1440x2392
SettingCardFragment: (Drawable)Background.png resolution: 1260x2240
SettingCardFragment:   (Bitmap)Background.png resolution: 1260x2240
```

Why did the resolution became 1260x2240 from 1440x2560?

If who know this, help me please~

Comment: Hi, I guess the image matches both the width and height of the screen, right?

Comment: Are you sure it is an xxxhdpi device and you are not seeing a scaled up version of the xxhdpi?

Comment: @X09 Why do the image size match screen? I just read it into program, I didn't apply it to any View.

Comment: @Jim, Yeah sorry you're right. Seems kind of strange. But you're sure about the resolution of the image right?

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani Yes, I had tried leave only the one xxxhdpi image, and deleted other. So I'm sure that used the xxxhdpi image.

Comment: @X09 Yes, I'm sure the resolution of the picture is 1440x2560, either from Windows or from the window of Android Studio.

Comment: Could it be a device specific issue? Which device are you using?

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani I used the Emulator of  Android Studio. And the devices are Nexus5(xxhdpi), Nexus 6P(xxxhdpi) and Pixel XL(xxxhdpi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. You are using a device with density 3.5 (like the Nexus 6p). You can check the density with this code `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`. In these kind of devices xxxhdpi is used and then scaled.

So if we do the scaling math - `image_size / xxxhdpi_density * device_density` you get the dimensions you are seeing:

> 2560 / 4 * 3.5 = 2240
>
> 1440 / 4 * 3.5 = 1260

Comment: Yes, you solved my problem, and you let me know how the size change.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources()
```

decodeResource will adapt the resoluten for your device.

If you want the original resolution then first open an `InputStream` for the resource and then use `BitmapFactory.decodeFromStream()`.