# Can I keep fix the same resolution of the same image when the devices have different densities?

Tags: android, image, drawable, resolution, screen-density

I asked a question yesterday.

[Why do resolutions become smaller after a image file be read by program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43894183/why-do-resolutions-become-smaller-after-a-image-file-be-read-by-program)

Very thanks the people helped me.

They let me know that **if I use the devices having different densities, the resolutions of the same image may be changed.**

For example:

I have a image with resolution 1440x2560 and a device with density 3.5.

The revolution will become 1260x2240 after the image be read into the program.

But I don't want the resolutions of the images to be changed, because the proportion of the images on the screen will be different.

I tried to find a solution, but I failed.

Is there a convenient way to fix the same resolution of the same image on the different devices with different densities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your images to be adjusted by Android, I understand they are drawables even if you didn't explicitly mention it, add them to the `drawable-nodpi` directory.